# Interface between CardDav server and MySQL database

Tags: mysql, webdav

My web app uses mysql to store contact data.  I'd like to sync this data via carddav with mobile devices.  I understand carddav is based on a file system, not a database.  What software is available to act as an interface or wrapper to make the carddav server work with mysql?  or other relational database?

Comment: CardDAV is a network protocol, it doesn't care whether the data comes from a database, a file system, or is randomly generated. I realize this doesn't answer your question, but I didn't want you to assume that you had to write data to files first.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [Bedework](https://www.apereo.org/bedework).

Comment: Yeah, we found them too.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Baikal just added this feature!!!

Most dav servers are file system based.  If you use SabreDav you can build a virtual filesystem based on your own backend.  Baikal is a project that uses sabredav, and a virtual file system. Until recently it stored its data in sqllite.  Now it supports both mysql and sqlite.

Its still not 100% mature, but its a great starting point.  Playing around with it, I have been able to create contacts directly in the DB (by uploading vcard blobs to a table) and then having them show on my ipad addressbook.

After evaluating many systems, ones built on sabredav like baikal tend to be the simplest to build on.  Fruxx is something else you may also check out.  Its a hosted system, but will soon have an api.

Last if you are looking for a very elaborate system, then take a look at tine20.  It supports activesync (illegally in the usa), carddav, caldav, and has a decent extjs web ui.  It natively stores contact information in its mysql store, which is nice since you can update a contact through a sql statement without having to build a vcf file.   Where tine doesnt make sense is that it uses a bit more resources because of all the features it offers, and the complexity has ensured that it has a VERY complicated database schema.  In other words, you are probably better off creating a rest api on the tine source code rather than doing bare sql inserts.

http://baikal-server.com/

Comment: Can you provide a link or elaborate a bit?

Comment: Your answer has been flagged as low quality answer (this is done by an automatic process that flags short answers). Could you add a link?